# `url('')` doesn't produce https URL despite correct APP_URL

Tags: laravel

I have the app URL defined in my `.env` file as follows:

`APP_URL='https://api.myapp.com'`

When I do `php artisan tinker` and check what `url('')`, produces, it's `https://api.myapp.com`, as expected.

However, when I use the `url('')` function in my blade templates to produce an API URL for the Ajax methods, I run into some trouble. Here's how the code is in my blade file:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "{{ url('') }}/api/image-cache/bust",
    // truncated
```

When this gets rendered as HTML, the generated URL is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "http://api.myapp.com/api/image-cache/bust",
    // truncated
```

Notice the "http" at the start, instead of the expected "https". I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Try clearing the config cache. `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Are you accessing the page over `https://`?

Comment: This `{{ url('/') }}` will return APP_URL doesn't matter if it's http or https...or better use directly `env('APP_URL')`

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{ config('app.url') }}/api/image-cache/bust` instead , also check if your `config/app.php` url is something like this `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://api.myapp.com'),`