# Why Laravel route remains http in an https APP_URL environment

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8, adminlte

I am using **Laravel 8.x on php 7.4**.

Also using AdminLTE views to authenticate, and they say they use the url() helper to do so, then for going live, I changed the AppServiceProvider to

```
public function boot(UrlGenerator $url)
{
    if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
        $url->forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

**However:**

1. Asked for a secure page(name it '*page1*').
2. As middleware auth is applied to that route, returned login page.
3. Filled user/pass fields and clicked login(submit) button.
4. It tries to fall back to *page1* with http: scheme!!??
5. Server rejects it because insecure, to continue is impossible.

I already looked/tried these:

https://dcblog.dev/laravel-force-https-with-url-helper

[`url('')` doesn't produce https URL despite correct APP_URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339724/url-doesnt-produce-https-url-despite-correct-app-url)

[Laravel HTTPS routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409807/laravel-https-routes)

**Why are my fallbacks routes being downgraded to http:// after login??**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way that AdminLTE request pages by default. It uses *url()* helper to serve pages. So, to force secure, there should be specified the boolean param as true.

If this is not possible, you can try to specify in the AdminLTE pages that those routes produced by the helper, are prefixed by the *APP_URL* var of your .env file.

So, having your APP_URL var set in the environment file to something like:
APP_URL = https://myadminlte.educational.lan

Then the **config/adminlte.php** configuration file in section "URLs" should be like this:

```
'use_route_url' => false,
'dashboard_url' => env('APP_URL').'/home',
'logout_url' => env('APP_URL').'/logout',
'login_url' => env('APP_URL').'/login',
'register_url' => env('APP_URL').'/register',
```

That is the solution I found. It worth trying to set *use_route_url* to true and having **properly set named routes**, try again. Or to have in front the auth pages so you can force *{{route('login')}}* instead of *{{ $login_url }}*